# Angular 7 cannot find files, despite the file being in all folders

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, angular7

I have started two new angular apps in Angular 7, and I keep running into the problem that it cannot find any files. In one app, I tried to use an image, in another I tried to access a json file with an http call.

I have clicked on the path to the json file (which was `http://localhost:4200/questions.json`), but instead of following that url, the browser goes to `http://localhost:4200`. I suspect this might be the problem.

Am I on the right track with this thought? And are there settings in Angular 7 that I can change so I can load images and json files in localhost?
I've read on stackoverflow that it might be caused by someone importing `HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule`, but I don't use that anywhere.

In case anyone wants to see the code for the http call:

In the app component:

```
this.questionsServiceService.getQuestions()
 .subscribe(
 response => console.log(response),
 err => console.log(err)
 )
```

The service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class QuestionsServiceService {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

  getQuestions(){
    return this.http.get('questions.json')
  }
}
```

I have placed questions.json in every possible folder (including the root and even those above it) to make sure it is somewhere. I've also tried searching for it in `./questions.json` and `app/questions.json` with no luck.

I have made a few apps in Angular 2 and did not have any of these problems (with either images or http calls).

Edit: I have tried putting an image in from file in the second app too, which doesn't work, but adding an image with a url from internet does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a relative path beginning from your `app` folder.
Angular is starting FileRequest from the base folder (app) so try something like this request:

```
 this._http.sendGet('./assets/questions.json')
```

I suggest putting files that you want to load or read into your assets folder.

I'm not 100% sure but I got in my mind that files which aren't under the assets folder are ignored when you use the build commands and got only included to your application if you place them inside of the folder.

Comment: Ah, so all files you want to access now have to be in assets? (the json file was also in the app and src folder, which didn't work)
Putting it in `assets` and using that link seems to have done it. For both images and json files. Thanks!

Comment: glad to help! I suggest to put Images in a subfolder (assets/images) just to keep a good overview and group files usefull

Answer (score 0):

Ways to achieve this, :

**First** :  In your service rewrite the GET method as

```
getQuestions(){
return this.http.get('./assets/questions.json')
```

}

**Reason** : assets folder in angular is for static file serving. Rest is skipped.

**Second** : Just call 'REQUIRE'

```
const content = require('../../questions.json');
```

**Note** : If you use the AOT compiler you have to add the node type definitions by adjusting tsconfig.app.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
"types": ["node"],
...
},
...
```

**Third** : import as JSON

```
import data  from './questions.json';
export class AppComponent  {
json:any = data;
}
```